# Wordpress Json API Cache

Tags: json, wordpress, api, caching

I am using Wordpress as a feed for an iPhone app by using the json api plugin to feed the data from site to application. It is however quite slow so I'm trying to find a way to cache the request. I haven't found a solution that actually works/explains how to do this well, can anyone provide any guidance oh how/wether this can be done?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution? Have you tried doing something from your backend like using caching plugins to cache at least database queries that repeats every time? I'm using JSON to get the data I want and it's not that bad. At least 1 sec to grab everything from posts on EC2 server

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using [wordpress transient API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).
eg.

```
 $transient_name = 'some_api_req_param1';
 $transient_value = get_transient($transient_name); 
 if( false !== $transient_value){
  echo $transient_value;
 }else{
  //$result = ...
  //fetch your data here
  //in the end save the data in the transient
  $expiration_time = 60*60*24*7;//in second 
  set_transient($transient_name,$result,$expiration_time);
}
```